# Notation for Partial Functions

Tags: functions, definition

Suppose we have sets $f$, $A$ and $B$ such that

$f\subset A\times B$ and $\forall x\in A\space \forall y,z\in B: [(x,y)\in f \land (x,z)\in f \implies y=z]$

i.e. $f$ is a partial function mapping $A$ to $B$.

Question: Can we then justify defining $\forall x\in A:\forall y \in B:[ f(x)=y\iff (x,y)\in f]$ allowing us to make all the substitutions entailed by equality?

**Edit 1:**

Or, alternatively, without equality...

$\forall x\in A: [f(x)\in B \iff \exists y:[y\in B \land (x,y)\in f]]$?

**Edit 2:**

The latter definition can be derived from the former. Not sure the other way, so they may not be *equivalent*.

---

### **Follow-up (One year later)**

I have found that the following construct works well for a partial function $f$ of one variable mapping part of set $A$ to set $B$ where the subset $D\subset X$ is the domain of definition:

$\forall x:[x\in D \implies f(x)\in B]$

For a partial function $f$ of two variables mapping part of set $A\times B$ to set $C$ where the subset $D\subset A\times B$ is the domain of definition:

$\forall x,y: [(x,y)\in D\implies f(x,y)\in C]$

**Example**

Suppose, for some reason, you want to define exponentiation on $\mathbb{N}$, leaving $0^0$ undefined.

Let $D=\mathbb{N}^2 - (0,0)$. Then we can define exponentiation as follows

1. $\forall x,y:[(x,y)\in D \implies x^y \in \mathbb{N}]$
2. $\forall x,y:[(x,y) \in D\implies x^0=1]$
3. $0^1=0$
4. $\forall x,y:[(x,y)\in D\implies x^{y+1}=x^y\cdot x]$

Or equivalently...

1. $\forall x,y:[x\in \mathbb{N} \land y\in \mathbb{N} \land \neg [x=0 \land y=0] \implies x^y\in \mathbb{N}]$
2. $\forall x:[x\in \mathbb{N} \land x\ne 0] \implies x^0=1]$
3. $0^1=0$
4. $\forall x,y:[x\in \mathbb{N} \land y\in \mathbb{N} \land \neg [x=0 \land y=0] \implies x^{y+1}=x^y\cdot x]$

Comment: I'm not sure what your intention is, however, if $f$ is a partial function, then $\forall x \in A : P(f(x))$ is incorrect, as $f$ is not defined for all $x \in A$. I can suggest one thing: consider the set $B^\bot = B \cup \{\bot\}$, where $\bot$ denotes the special element meaning _undefined_. Then, use function $f^\bot : A \to B^\bot$ defined as $$f^\bot(x) = \begin{cases} y & \text{ for } (x,y) \in f, \\ \bot & \text{ if } f \text{ is not defined on } x,\end{cases}$$ with any formulas you like, perhaps including $(f(x) \neq \bot \implies \ldots)$ when necessary.

Comment: If $f$ is not defined for some $x\in A$, can we not write $f(x)\notin B$? What problems might you run into if you allowed this?

Comment: Just a little one: what is exactly $f(x)$?

Comment: In isolation, it might not have much meaning, but I would like to know what contradictions might you obtain if you interpreted $f(x)\notin B$ where $x\in A$ to mean $\not \exists y :[y\in B \land (x,y)\in f]$.

Comment: You cannot use undefined things, like $1/0$; $f(x)$ is meaningless and any expression it appears in is meaningless too. You can use $f^\bot(x) \notin B$ with the standard $\notin$ operator, or redefine the _whole expression_ $f(x) \notin B$ as what you want. However, in this expression the symbol $\notin$ won't be related in any way to the standard operator, besides its graphical similarity. It would be the same as defining $\psi(f,x,B)$, just with a more intuitive appearance. Note there is no $f(x)$, i.e. application; likewise, the parentheses in $f(x)$ in your expression are mere separators.

Comment: @dtldarek A stronger argument than any supposed meaninglessness would be a demonstration that my definition would lead to some contradiction, e.g. a counterexample leading to $f(x)\in B \land f(x)\notin B$.

Comment: @dtldarek If $D$ is the subset of $A$ such that $\forall x:[x\in D \iff x\in A\land \exists y:[y\in B \land (x,y)\in f]]$, i.e. $D$ is the domain on which $f$ is a total function, then it can be shown using my latter definition that $\forall x\in A :[f(x)\in B \iff x\in D].$

Comment: The burden of proof is on the side of the proof provider. In other words, suppose that I would start write some gibberish, using a notation that you have never seen before, some parts being clearly nonsensical to you, and then claim that it's a proof. Would you accept such a derivation? There are many things allowed when doing a sketch or informal reasoning, but with a proof you need to defined everything you are using (unless the context does it for you) and then each step should be valid. This is not the case with your novel usage of $f(x)$.

Comment: @dtldarek Judging by Berci's response, it isn't all that novel. It makes doing formal proofs about partial functions much easier. Note that this definition also works for total functions.

Comment: I think you misunderstood Berci's answer.
Sure, you can write $f(x)$, but this is allowed only if $(x,y) \in f$ for some $y$ (there's even an emphasis on "_whenever it exists_").
On the other hand, you intend to use it in general, i.e. also when it's not defined. This particular point is the one I have trouble with (and I assure you, it's not only me).

Comment: $f(x)$ in isolation could be seen as a sentence fragment. It only makes sense embedded in an syntactically corrected sentence, e.g. $f(x)\in B$. And yes, this is true if and only if $\exists y:[y\in B \land (x,y)\in f].$ I know that others have trouble with this. That is why I posted this question. My definition just seemed so reasonable to me. And it doesn't seem to lead to any contradictory or unexpected results.

Comment: Believe me, I understand your point of view and see its advantages. Moreover, I think it is alright, given that _you are going to define it_. It's not that $f(x)\in B$ is true/false, it's true/undefined. As long as you precisely state what you have in mind, you are allowed to use it, but not before. You _can_ define your $\bullet(x) \in B$ notation to whatever you want, just remember to do it (or define $f^\bot$ and use $f^\bot(x) \in B$ using standard definitions, or yet something else).

Comment: @dtldarek Since the latter "definition" can be derived from the former (not sure the other way), we should probably concentrate on the equality, $f(x)=y \iff (x,y)\in f$. Given that images under $f$ are unique, this shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: Of course, $(x,y) \in f \implies f(x) = y$, also if $f$ is defined at $x$, then $f(x) = y \implies (x,y) \in f$, however, if $f$ isn't defined at $x$, then what does $f(x) = y$ mean? You can extend "$=$" by setting $(\mathtt{undefined} = y)$ to $\mathtt{false}$, but that is exactly what $\bot$ and $f^\bot$ do. Also, you can define $\bullet_1(\bullet_2) = \bullet_3$ as "if $\bullet_1$ is undefined at $\bullet_2$ then $\mathtt{false}$, else use the standard definition". Finally, you can extend $\iff$ similarly to "$=$" before. Any of these would make $f(x) =y \iff (x,y) \in f$ a valid statement.

Comment: Admittedly, it would be difficult to attach a precise meaning in everyday language to $f(x)=y$ in that case, but no more so than attaching a meaning to your $f^{\bot}$ construction. If $f$ isn't defined at $x$, then $(x,y)\in f$ is false, and, by definition, so is $f(x)=y$. $f(x)\in B$ would also be false.

Comment: Great, so you are defining $\bullet_1(\bullet_2)=\bullet_3$ as $(\bullet_2,\bullet_3) \in \bullet_1$. Similarly $\bullet_1(\bullet_2) \in \bullet_3$ would be $\exists y : y \in B \land (\bullet_2,y) \in \bullet_1$. This is all fine, just be aware, that "$=$" and "$\in$" in there do not have their standard meaning (i.e. you've just redefined it).

Comment: Even for total functions of 1 variable, the standard approach for a long time (centuries?) has been to define $f(x)=y \iff (x,y) \in f$. Do you have a problem with that? I am proposing to do the same thing with partial functions. It seems to work.

Comment: I think that this is a horrible misunderstanding. Your approach _does work_. Just, when writing a paper, or whatever else you intend to do with it, _define it before use_ (otherwise it would not work). I suggested the other approach, because it let's you write expressions such as $f^\bot(x) +^\bot 5 \in B$ (and the ugly indexes can be dropped with appropriate context or commentary). However, with your approach, you will have to redefine each standard operator to work with partial functions (i.e. handle the possible misses and related special cases).

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned property of $f$ being a partial function enables us to write $f(x)$ for the *unique* value $y$ such that $(x,y)\in f$, *whenever it exists*.

An alternative way to define partial function from $A$ to $B$ is to define it as a function $D\to B$ with some $D\subseteq A$ (called the domain of $f$), and then $f(x)$ exists [and is unique] iff $x\in D$.

Comment: The latter is what I have usually seen. How common a convention is the former?

Comment: Well, the two definitions are *equivalent*. It is then jus ta matter of taste which one to choose as 'the' definition.

Comment: Thanks, but how commonly used is this convention? Can it truly be something novel as suggested by dtldarek? The few definitions of partial functions that I have seen don't explicitly define the very useful $f(x)$ notation .

Answer (score 1):

Partial functions are a special case of relations. There is a notion of composition of relations, given in the case of binary relations by

$$ a RS b \Longleftrightarrow \exists c : a R c \wedge c S b $$

(or maybe $SR$ rather than $RS$ depending on your ordering convention)

There is also a corresponding notion of a partial *element* of a set, which can be identified with a partial function from the one point set to your set.

In particular, there is exactly one partial element of any set that is not an ordinary total element. It is not terribly unreasonable to call this the "undefined" element.

Along these lines, if $x$ is not in the domain of $f$, one would have $f(x)$ being the undefined element.

You can even go so far as to insist that the truth of an equation like $x = y$ has a *partial* truth value rather than a (total) truth value.

I've never seen anyone attempt to specify a formal syntax and semantics based on partial functions like this, and I've not tried too hard to work it out myself, so I can't really offer "a lot can be reasonably done, but I don't know exactly the right way to set up the details".

Looking at the internal logic of the category of sets and partial functions is probably a good approach to get something that is at least reasonable.

Comment: Interesting to know that there may be no widely accepted formalism for partial functions.

Comment: @Dan: I suppose I should add that one could construct the category of sets and partial functions, and one could do the normal thing to talk about the internal logic of said category. I haven't gone through this exercise, though, so I don't know how it works out.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of bother for such a simple idea.

Comment: @Dan: Depends on your background. Since I've studied some categorical logic, it is a natural place for me to begin to hammer out something I know will at least be consistent and sensible without requiring trial and error.

Comment: As I have pointed out elsewhere, even for a total function $f:A\to B$, we define $f(x)=y \iff (x,y)\in f$. Quite a mainstream notion as it turns out. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Notation

Comment: @Dan: Maybe I have been reading the wrong things into your request. e.g. one of the points I want to make is an approach based on partial functions would let you meaningfully write $f(x)$ all on its own even when $x$ is not in the domain of $f$, and $f(x) = y$ as an ordinary equation, rather than reading "$f(x) = y$" as one large term that can't be broken into meaningful parts. Maybe this is merely tangential to your interests.

Comment: I don't think we formally define $f(x)$ all on its own even for total functions. Rather, we define either $f(x)=y$ or $f(x)\in$ some set.

Comment: @Dan: The syntax I usually see is things like "if $x$ is a term of type $X$ and $f$ is a term of type $X \to Y$ then $f(x)$ is a term of type $Y$" and so forth, and semantics is "the term $f(x)$ is interpreted as the unique value $y$ with $(x,y)$ in the (graph of the) interpretation of $f$". (and by 'x' I meant the interpretation of the term 'x')

Comment: In a formal proof, you won't see a definition anything like $\forall x\in A: [f(x) \iff ... ]$. The $f(x)$ would have to be embedded in logical expression, e.g. $f(x)=y.$

Comment: You can also see things like $f(f(x))$ or $f(x) \in S$ or $\lambda x.f(x)$ or other things; ideally, you want $f(x)$ to be a term that can be combined functionally with other terms.

Comment: It doesn't seem that you can formally define $f(x)$ in isolation, even for total functions.

Comment: @DanChristensen, in my opinion - and I'm far from an expert - but anyway, in my opinion, the only situations in which you can't formally define $f(x)$ in isolation are situations where you're working inside a silly framework. In any reasonable framework, you will have types, terms will belong to types, and one of those types ("Prop") is the type to which the term $f(x)=y$ belongs. There's really no reason to privilege "Prop" any more than strictly necessary. I think the tendency to not take $f(x)$ seriously (in isolation) is basically an artifact of the overemphasis of FOL for 70-80 years.

Comment: Where by FOL, I mean first-order logic.

Answer (score 0):

When you write $f(x)∈B$, you involve more definitions than you have here. The rest of the statements depends on those definitions, and so the answer to your question, I think, can be given only after we clarify what you mean.